# Kinesis with DLQ message struct

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, dead-letter, amazon-kinesis, dlq

I defined a DLQ for Kinesis stream and now I'm creating a lambda that will receive SQS messages and handle them.
I saw at [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg//with-kinesis.html#services-kinesis-errors) that the message format is:

```
{
    "requestContext": {
        "requestId": "c9b8fa9f-5a7f-xmpl-af9c-0c604cde93a5",
        "functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:myfunction",
        "condition": "RetryAttemptsExhausted",
        "approximateInvokeCount": 1
    },
    "responseContext": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "executedVersion": "$LATEST",
        "functionError": "Unhandled"
    },
    "version": "1.0",
    "timestamp": "2019-11-14T00:38:06.021Z",
    "KinesisBatchInfo": {
        "shardId": "shardId-000000000001",
        "startSequenceNumber": "49601189658422359378836298521827638475320189012309704722",
        "endSequenceNumber": "49601189658422359378836298522902373528957594348623495186",
        "approximateArrivalOfFirstRecord": "2019-11-14T00:38:04.835Z",
        "approximateArrivalOfLastRecord": "2019-11-14T00:38:05.580Z",
        "batchSize": 500,
        "streamArn": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-2:123456789012:stream/mystream"
    }
}
```

I searched and didn't find a built-in struct by [AWS SDK for Go API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/) and didn't find.

If anyone knows if there is an existing struct that I can reuse? or I will need to create and maintain a new struct